# Implementing begin() and end() for doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, iterator, stdlist

I have written my own container class whose original internal data structure was the `std::list`. I then needed to create my own doubly linked list. I have now implemented my own doubly linked list as well as my own iterator for the linked list, but I'm having problems getting it to behave like `std::list`, particularly with `begin()` and `end()`.

From what I understand, `begin()` should point the first node, and `end()` should point one element past the last element. I need to make sure that when I call `end()` that I can decrement back to the valid last element. I also need to make sure that I can do your normal traversals like...

```
while (beg != end ) { do something; beg++; }
```

Essentially my linked list just uses nodes that contain a data element, a pointer to the previous node and a pointer to the next node.

When I first tried to implement my `end()`, I just had the last node's next pointer be a `nullptr`. It works on its own but does not act the same way as the stl.

Any advice on how to implement the `begin()` and `end()` the same way the standard library does?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/

Comment: Side Note: Have you considered a custom allocator for std::list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could introduce a sentinel node and have a circular linked list.

A sketch:

```
class List
{
    private:
    struct Node {
        Node* previous;
        Node* next;

        Node() : previous(this), next(this) {}
    };

    struct DataNode : Node {
        int data;
    };

    public:
    class iterator
    {
        friend class List;

        private:
        iterator(Node* node) : m_node(node) {}

        public:
        iterator() : m_node(0) {}

        iterator& operator ++() {
            m_node = m_node->next;
            return *this;
        }

        int& operator * () {
            // Note: Dereferncing the end (sentinal node) is undefined behavior.
            return reinterpret_cast<DataNode*>(m_node)->data;
        }

        // More iterator functions.

        private:
        Node* m_node;
    };

    public:
    List() : m_sentinal(new Node) {}

    iterator begin() { return iterator(m_sentinal->next); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(m_sentinal); }

    iterator insert(iterator position, int data) {
        DataNode* data_node = new DataNode; // pass data
        Node* current = position.m_node;
        data_node->next = current;
        data_node->previous = current->previous;
        current->previous->next = data_node;
        current->previous = data_node;
        return iterator(current);
    }

    void append(int data) {
        insert(end(), data);
    }

    private:
    Node* m_sentinal;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea of the sentinel is what I think I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your end node cannot be null because you can't implement `--` (going backwards) if all you have is null. You'll need to make a sentinel for the end node that at least knows how to get back to the last node in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your container should create a end node that is always available. This is what you will return from begin() when the container is empty. Your last real node should always set it's next node to this end node.